# Creating an SQL query that eliminates duplicate months/year

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssrs-2008

Hello Stack Overflow community - hopefully i'm on the right track with this one, but i'm trying to write a query where a report out shows the number of orders placed by month/year. The report currently brings up all the days where i'm trying to join them all by month/year collectively. Hopefully this makes sense, i'm pretty new to this, be gentle please ;)

```
select distinct month(o.orderdate) 'Month',
         year(o.orderdate) 'Year', sum(od.Quantity) as Orders 
from     OrderDetails od 
join     Products p
on       od.ProductID = p.ProductID
join     Orders o
on       od.OrderID = o.OrderID
group by o.orderdate
Order by year, month asc;
```

Comment: I'm guessing from the SSRS tag that you are really using SQL Server, so I removed the mysql tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `group by` what you want to define each row.  In your case, that is the year and month:

```
select year(orderdate) as yyyy, month(o.orderdate) as mm,
       sum(od.Quantity) as Orders 
from OrderDetails od join
     Products p
     on od.ProductID = p.ProductID join
     Orders o
     on od.OrderID = o.OrderID
group by year(o.orderdate), month(o.orderdate) 
Order by yyyy, mm asc;
```

Notes:

- I changed the column names to `yyyy` and `mm` so they do not conflict with the reserved words `year` and `month`.
- Don't use single quotes for column aliases.  This is a bad habit that will eventually cause problems in your query.
- I always use `as` for column aliases (to help prevent missing comma mistakes), but never for table aliases.
- The `product` table is not needed for this query.

Edit:  If you want a count of *orders*, which your query suggests, then this might be more appropriate:

```
select year(o.orderdate) as yyyy, month(o.o.orderdate) as mm,
       count(*) as Orders 
from orders o
group by year(o.orderdate), month(o.orderdate) 
Order by yyyy, mm asc;
```

Comment: Ahh ok, thank you so much for the help @GordonLinoff !

Answer (score 0):

You have to group by month and year

```
select distinct month(o.orderdate) 'Month',
     year(o.orderdate) 'Year', sum(od.Quantity) as Orders 
from     OrderDetails od 
join     Products p
on       od.ProductID = p.ProductID
join     Orders o
on       od.OrderID = o.OrderID
group by month(o.orderdate), year(o.orderdate)
Order by [Year],[month]
```